# Get the norm of a linear operator

Tags: normed-spaces, linear-transformations

*Consider $C=\Big\{(z_n)\subset \mathbb{C}:\exists z\in\mathbb{C};\ z_n\to z\Big\}$ and $C_0=\Big\{(z_n)\subset \mathbb{C}: z_n\to 0\Big\}$ with the norm $||\cdot||_\infty$. If $\Lambda:C\longrightarrow C_0$ is an linear operator defined by:
$$\Lambda(z_n)=(z,z-z_1,z-z_2,\ldots)$$
where $z=\lim z_n$, prove that $\Lambda$ is bijective and $||\Lambda||=||\Lambda^{-1}||=2$*

It's ease prove that $\Lambda$ is bijective. I was trying deduce that $||\Lambda||=2$:
$$||\Lambda||=\sup_{(z_n)\in C-\{0\}}\frac{||\Lambda(z_n)||_\infty}{||(z_n)||_\infty}=\sup_{(z_n)\in C-\{0\}} \frac{|z|}{||(z_n)||_\infty}=..(?)$$
Any idea for this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since $|z_n|\leq \|(z_n)\|_\infty$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the limit must be such that $|z|\leq \|(z_n)\|_\infty$. Thus
$$|z-z_n|\leq |z|+|z_n|\leq 2 \|z\|_\infty$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, which shows that $\|\Lambda\|\leq 2$.

To show that the equality holds, consider for example the sequence $(z_n)$ with $z_0=-1$ and $z_n=1$ otherwise. It has unit norm and limit $1$, so $\Lambda (z_n)$ is $$1,2,0,0,0,0,\cdots$$
which has norm $2$.